# Github api issues by label with spaces

Tags: api, github, label

Hi I have tried everything to get my issues by label. The problem is my label contains spaces:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token my_token' https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:Ready for release%20milestone:2.2.10%20repo:valllllll2000/test_github_api
```

I have tried replacing the spaces by %20 but it does not work or even writing "Ready for release".

The label is 'Ready for release' is there a way to make this work or do I have to change the label? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the github support I got the correct url: `curl -i -H 'Authorization: token my_token' 'https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:%22Ready%20for%20release%22+milestone:2.2.10+repo:valllllll2000/test_github_api'`

Comment: if you are using this github API endpoint: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-repository-issues The spaces in a label are replaced by "+" signs. So for example if my label name was "feature request" my url param would be ```?labels=feature+request```